# Count WordPress Post view onClick using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

How can I count post views of my WordPress posts when click on a button using AJAX?

Currently it's counting the post view whenever I refresh the page, I want to call tha funtion with ajax.

Please check the code I am currently using to show post view count

Inside the functions.php

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'count_views' ) ) :    
// Get the value of view
function count_views($postID) {   
    
    $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';    
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);    
    
    if($count ==''){
        $count = 1;        
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);        
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '1');    
    } else {        
        $count++;        
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);    
    }
}
endif;
```

Then on single.php I have called the funtion **count_views** with **get_the_ID();**

```
<?php count_views(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

To retrieve the view count I have used:

```
<li>
<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>                            
<?php
if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wpb_post_views_count', true) == '') {
    echo '0';
} else {
    echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wpb_post_views_count', true);
};
?>                             
</li>
```

How can I call the count_views(get_the_ID()) funtion using javascript Ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add actions to your functions.php file for WordPress. You can then designate callback functions that return the data you are looking for. PHP code below:

```
// You add two actions here, so it can be accessed from outside the WP CMS
add_action( 'wp_ajax_project_get_post_count', 'project_get_post_count_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_project_get_post_count', 'project_get_post_count_callback' );

function project_get_post_content_callback() {

  if(!empty($_POST['ID'])){
    $postID == $_POST['ID'];
    $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';    
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    $response['views'] = $count;
    if($response['views'] ==''){
        $response['views'] = 0;
    }
    wp_send_json( $response );
  }
}
```

Once you have that setup, in javascript you need to do an AJAX post, passing the action name using the action attribute in `POST`. This below will get you mostly there. You'll need to format it correctly to be able to get your data. This example is also in `jQuery`, vanilla JS will be different. JS code below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxfullurl,
    data: {
        'action': 'project_get_post_count',
        'ID':<YOURIDHERE>
    }
});
```

The last piece you'll need is the AJAX URL (`ajaxfullurl`). WordPress provides a way to get that. This is the PHP code that you'll need to extract the URL for AJAX calls on your WordPress website.

```
echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
```

Comment: Hi cngodles! Thanks for the answer, it solved the problem :)

Comment: Excellent. I did notice that I messed up the function name `project_get_post_content_callback()`, it should be `project_get_post_count_callback()`.